# new search box looks janky when browser width narrow enough for horizontal scrolling

Tags: bug, user-interface, top-bar

This is not a post about the positives or negatives of the new navbar color at the top of all StackExchange sites, but it does have to do indirectly with the navbar color.

Now that the expandable search box has gone away, an interesting quirk occurs when you have your browser narrow enough to cause horizontal scrolling to kick in.

---

**Exhibit A:**  the browser scrollbar has activated because user has reduced the width to a size roughly less than the 980px width of the `#content` div container.
[image: browser scrollbar has activated]

---

**Exhibit B:** the search box looks ok, right?
[image: search box looks ok]

---

**Exhibit C:** well, maybe not...because what is the search box doing there, partly in a black background, and partly in a white background?
[image: search box looks odd]

---

To conclude: the top navbar appeareance should persist across the full width of the browser when the browser size is reduced, even if the search box in the right corner makes that more challenging.

Comment: This happened even before the topbar was changed... To solve this, they need to add the following CSS: `.topbar { min-width: 1000px; }`.. try it in your browser.. it will work.